# How execute javascript after a component change in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

My code works fine when I write in browser localhost:4200/pay;id=1. This show Pay component with  credit card fields generated by a external javascript (This javascript script is loaded from this component). But if i come from another component to this, Pay component doesn't show the credit card fields but load external script. How can I fix this?

My code

first.component.ts

```
let datos = {
  id:'6'
}
this.router.navigate(['pay',datos]);
```

pay.component.ts

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadScripts();
}

 loadScripts() {
     this.dynamicScriptLoader.load('2payjs').then(data => {
       // Script Loaded Successfully
       console.log('All elements loaded successfully')
       this.loadElement();
 
     }).catch(error => console.log(error));
}

loadElement(){
    let that = this;
    let id = this.router.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
      // Initialize the JS Payments SDK client.
      let jsPaymentClient = new  TwoPayClient('AVLRNG');
  
      // Create the component that will hold the card fields.
      let component = jsPaymentClient.components.create('card');
  
      component.mount('#card-element');

      // Handle form submission.
      document.getElementById('payment-form').addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
    
        /// Extract the Name field value
        const billingDetails = {
          name: document.querySelector('#name').value
        };

        // Call the generate method using the component as the first parameter
        // and the billing details as the second one
        jsPaymentClient.tokens.generate(component, billingDetails).then((response) => {
          //console.log(response.token);
          let data = {
            token:response.token
          }
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
   queryParams: {
       id: 1,
    },
    queryParamsHandling: 'merge'
};
this.router.navigate(['pay'], navigationExtras);
```

you need `navigationExtras` in order to create params in your router link and able to fetch by another component

Comment: I can pass data correctly, in pay component my external library loads correctly but it does not generate the cards fields. It generate the cards fields if I directly open pay component through the url

Answer (score 0):

Already solved. I just delete window load event listener.